Can setup File level log in Yii1 files to list on cloudwatch AWS
I want the logs of my Yii1 project list in the cloudwatch AWS. Yii2 have the extension for cloudwatch logs but not for Yii1.
I found this code but seems not working. I can't see the logs in the cloud watch.
Yii::import('CLogRoute');
use Aws\CloudWatchLogs\CloudWatchLogsClient;

class CloudWatchLogRoute extends CLogRoute
{
    public $logGroupName;
    public $logStreamName;
    public $awsRegion;
    public $awsKey;
    public $awsSecret;
    private $client;
    private $sequenceToken;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->client = new CloudWatchLogsClient([
            'region' => $this->awsRegion,
            'version' => 'latest',
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => $this->awsKey,
                'secret' => $this->awsSecret,
            ],
        ]);

        $this->createLogGroupAndStream();
    }

    protected function createLogGroupAndStream()
    {
        $logGroups = $this->client->describeLogGroups([
            'logGroupNamePrefix' => $this->logGroupName,
        ]);

        if (empty($logGroups['logGroups'])) {
            $this->client->createLogGroup(['logGroupName' => $this->logGroupName]);
        }

        $logStreams = $this->client->describeLogStreams([
            'logGroupName' => $this->logGroupName,
            'logStreamNamePrefix' => $this->logStreamName,
        ]);

        if (empty($logStreams['logStreams'])) {
            $this->client->createLogStream([
                'logGroupName' => $this->logGroupName,
                'logStreamName' => $this->logStreamName,
            ]);
        } else {
            $this->sequenceToken = $logStreams['logStreams'][0]['uploadSequenceToken'];
        }
    }

    protected function processLogs($logs)
    {
        $messages = array_map(function ($log) {
            return [
                'message' => $log[0],
                'timestamp' => round(microtime(true) * 1000),
            ];
        }, $logs);

        $params = [
            'logGroupName' => $this->logGroupName,
            'logStreamName' => $this->logStreamName,
            'logEvents' => $messages,
        ];

        if ($this->sequenceToken) {
            $params['sequenceToken'] = $this->sequenceToken;
        }

        $result = $this->client->putLogEvents($params);
        $this->sequenceToken = $result['nextSequenceToken'];
    }
}

Here is the configurations:
'components' => [
    'log' => [
        'class' => 'CLogRouter',
        'routes' => [
            [
                'class' => 'application.components.CloudWatchLogRoute',
                'logGroupName' => 'your-log-group-name',
                'logStreamName' => 'your-log-stream-name',
                'awsRegion' => 'your-aws-region',
                'awsKey' => 'your-aws-access-key',
                'awsSecret' => 'your-aws-secret-key',
                'levels' => 'error, warning', // Adjust log levels as needed
            ],
        ],
    ],
],

Is there a way the logs can be seen in the cloudwatch AWS? I am trying this code with my local setup and is running on docker. The project container is already pushing logs to cloudwatch on production server. And I believe same should work for local as well If logs are set to std.out. Can anyone suggest me where I am doing wrong.
Here is error I am getting:

